# What's wrong with this piece of VBA code that should return a number of days?

Tags: excel, vba

So I wrote this piece of code (it's actually part of a something bigger but this part gives me the problems) and I'm new to VBA so I can't figure out why this always returns 0 as the formula result.

```
Function test(begindatum As Date, einddatum As Date)  
Dim Days1  
If begindatum < 1 / 9 / 1996 And begindatum > 31 / 7 / 1986 Then  
    If einddatum > 31 / 8 / 1996 Then  
        Days1 = DateDiff("d", 1 / 9 / 1996, begindatum)  
    Else: Days1 = DateDiff("d", einddatum, begindatum)  
    End If  
End If  
test = Days1  
End Function
```

I tested with various dates btw, all of them returned the output 0.
Would appreciate it if someone could point out where I went wrong.

Kindly regards,
Daquicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dates;

```
 1 / 9 / 1996
```

are mathematical expressions - **1** *divided-by* **9** *divided by* **1996** - which will be zero when coerced to an integer type.

for a literal date use:

```
 If begindatum < #1/9/1996# and ...
```

Comment: Ty this works but The reason I did'n try that myself is because this works:                                                       Function test2(begindatum As Date, einddatum As Date)
test2 = DateDiff("d", 1 / 1 / 1990, Now)
End Function                                                        why does that work then?

Comment: Its the same as `DateDiff("d", 0, Now)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use DateSerial to convert all dates to integers, then compare them.

Comment: +1 this is better than #date# as it removes dmy/ymd confusion

Answer (score 0):

No spaces, proper # separator, and VBA always expects american (m/d/yy) format, so for september 1, use `#9/1/1996#`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share knowledge... you can also use the `CDate` function. It works pretty well and also accepts other date formats, as `CDate("01/Sep/1996")`.

Pay attention, however. Handle date may become a pain if you'll use it under different regional settings (global apps, for instance).